# How to Pass Objects in SpringBoot Rest Api with RedirectView?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, security

I have a project Website the front-end is Angular 8 and the back-end is Springboot Rest. I have this feature that allows the user to reset their password.

The User receives an email with id and token when the user initiated the change password. My springboot project sends an email with the generated URL link:
`e.g. https://mylocalhost:8080/password/user?id=1111&token=1234335345mcjf`

This link is being generated from the back-end side. The token is only alive around 30 min.

My problem is the URL it shows the token ID. My questions are:

1. I am not sure if this approach is secured, as the token is being displayed as parameters.. :(
2. Is there any way I can pass the token and user Id as objects not as parameters in the front end?

Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks a standard procedure for password reset. The link is open from email you can only use `GET` request and pass parameters as query params.

> However your approach may not be secured. Why ?

Because your token seems to never expire and it can be very dangerous.
Do you know about [JWT token](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-security-json-web-tokenjwt-hello-world) ?

`JWT` is a secure way to create a token which expires (you decide of valid duration).
Moreover you can add information in the token like `user id`, `user adress ip`, etc.

**For more information about password reset strategy, read [Forgot Password Best Practices](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-security-json-web-tokenjwt-hello-world)**.

Comment: Hello Martin, thanks for the reply. My token has expiration. It only lives for 30 minutes. I do check in the back-end that when the token has expired, I will be redirecting to an Access Denied Page.Yes, I know the JWT token however, the organization that I work with is using OAuth2 Kong as part of the standards.

Comment: Ok so if you have been sensitized to security, your approach is fine. 

Comment: I see.. I am now relieved. Thanks Martin. :)